# USB file transfer only works when HTC One X is connected in internet pass-through mode

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, file-system, file-transfer, htc-one-x

When I connect my HTC One X via USB to my PC, I can see my Android storage only when my phone  is connected in internet pass-through mode. I set the mode by `Settings > More > Mobile network sharing > USB Network setting`. If I select any other option I am unable to see my drives on phone. My Phone is running Android 4.1.1 and Sense 4+.